# How do I adjust the scale of items placed in a circle with Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I have a Geometry Nodes setup where I'm distributing 7 cylinders around a circle mesh and placing a star at the top of each of them. So far, so good.

However, I'm trying to achieve an effect with them similar to the MLB World Series trophy, where as they approach the front of the trophy, the posts get smaller. I'd also like the stars to get smaller as well, as their posts shorten.

How do I go about doing this? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

[image: World Series trophy]

This is my current node setup:
[image: Current node tree]

Comment: Here is another idea, it's basically like the given answer, just a bit different in how the poles are created and I've put scaled icospheres on top of the poles where you would want your stars: [scaled instances circle](https://blend-exchange.com/b/41mJLwjv/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is a node setup for the poles, so you know how to do it.

You have to add the flag manually with some additional nodes.

[image]